What is the best way to setup messaging with devices that might be anywhere on the internet?
Are there standard techniques/libraries that are used to implement IoT? How does a monitoring-and-control component setup a messaging connection to a monitoring device that might be tethered to a cellular network? Say that I am working in Python but the question also applies to C/C++.

what is the specific problem that you are trying to solve? ... this site is for focused questions that have one correct answer ... questions that have multiple correct answers are off topic as being too broad

The basic answer is that it will usually be the devices which connect to the server, rather than the opposite. This has been covered a few times around here. Beyond that there are lots of possibilities, from using standard protocols like MQTT to using custom protocols (ideally HTTP-based), but the topic is way too broad for an answer.

Had thought it was narrow enough - "the best" and "Python" or "C/C++" within the IoT context. I have a good spread of network messaging experience from ASN1 and BER through to protobuf, AMQP and restful. None of which do much about the specific requirements of IoT.

Your question is quite broad but...
MQTT is the protocol that is widely used in the context that you describe.
It has many features like :

Send messages without or with ACK
Payload Encryption
Widely supported in the Open Source world
There is libraries for many programing languages

And there is many other reasons...

Thanks for that. I am reasonably familiar with rabbitmq though not in the WAN context. MQTT seems to have similar feature set. What I seem to be discovering is that there are not really established IoT-specific frameworks that support monitoring and control of widely distributed devices. Like what Django does for websites. IoT has specific issues like connectivity from a central location to devices located inside cellular networks, Perhaps people are using MQTT or rolling their own.

Just an FYI. Further reading on MQTT makes it pretty clear. These are different technologies. If you are dealing with large numbers of devices (e.g. > 10k) and you have no need for "timely responses" then MQTT is the go-to solution. If are dealing with smaller numbers of devices and you wish to have an ongoing and more responsive interaction then MQTT is not so well suited.  Would you use MQTT to pan/zoom CCTV cameras? Different system requirements. The substantial community behind it is a good thing except where it makes it seem like the solution to everything.

As you haven't wrote any "use case" you get answers that tries to meet your questions. And when you wrote "cellular network" that indicate low bandwidth devices and thereof my answer.

Understood. After decades of working in the telephony field - from ISDN and POTS through to SIPS and FreePBX - "cellular network" to me now means 5G. not sure i can call that low bandwidth anymore :-)

Assumptions is the mother of all XXXXups.
And cool to meet another SIP/VoIP soul, I imagine we share a common/similar background.

We probably do. FYI. Full request time for WAN level messaging (from client through relay to service and back again) seems to be around 0.25s to 0.35s. That figure didnt change in any reliable way when switching from rpi on cellular to laptop on different LAN. Cellular may be slower but if the difference is significant to your requirements then this technique - whether MQTT or ansar - is not for you.

Oops. That was not the right answer - responding to a few forum topics at the moment. Yeah we have a couple of shared interests there - from telephony and computing through to sailing. My point was that I have seen cellular networks running faster than many office fibre setups. Still looking into claims of "real-time" in the MQTT literature. Given the store-and-forward nature of it, it's hard to imagine low latency. Hope that is more "on point".
